# drawing line between plotted points

Tags: pgfplots, plot

How do you have the line draw between points that have been plotted on a graph? Here's what I've done so far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\centering
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  width={8in},
  xtick={1,2,...,6},
  ytick={1,2,...,13},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin= -.5,
  xmax=7.5,
  ymin=-.5,
  ymax=13.5]

  \addplot [only marks] table {
1  1
2  3
3  5
4  6
5  8
6  10
7  12
8  13
};
\addplot [only marks,domain=0:8] ;
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just use

```
\addplot table {
```

I have used

```
\addplot+ [mark=*] table ...
```

just to show that you can change the marks this way. When you add options to `\addplot` don't forget to use `+` so that the options are appended instead of replacing the default options.

Code, with slight corrections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\centering
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  width={\linewidth},
  xtick={1,2,...,8},
  ytick={1,2,...,13},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin= 0,
  xmax=8.5,
  ymin=-.5,
  ymax=13.5]

  \addplot+ [mark=*] table {
1  1
2  3
3  5
4  6
5  8
6  10
7  12
8  13
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I add the arrows on the end of a line to show that it is continuous in both directions? Not in this example but in general for a line.

Comment: @Marcus Just use `\addplot+ [<->]...` To change arrow heads you may use `arrow.meta` library of `tikz`. For details, see `pgfmanual` at www.texdoc.net.

Comment: @Marcus Please consider  up voting and accepting the answers that solved your problem. For details please do read [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)